# How to handle loading events in controllers in ember

Tags: ember.js

What is a good way to show a reusable loading screen whilst controllers are performing time consuming actions such as server queries.  Ember provides shared loading route functionality for route transitions perhaps someone has been able to leverage these in controllers as well?

My current thinking is to implement actions in the ApplicationController to show and hide a loading div.  Controllers can then call these before and after time consuming actions. Perhaps someone has a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you have a few options. I would do one of these two:

1. Define a loading route/template. The `loading` template will be rendered into the outlet of the parent route and will be replaced by the current route's contents when the transition is complete. I did this once where I used a modal dialog to display a loading message.
2. Define actions in `ApplicationRoute`. Actions bubble from a controller, to the matching route, then up the route chain. If you define actions in the topmost route, you can send a message from any controller that will be caught. I currently have `startLoading` and `stopLoading` actions in my `ApplicationRoute`.

Comment: Thanks GJK I ended up defining actions in my ApplicationRoute as per your suggestion.  Also I moved most time consuming actions out of my controllers and into my routes.